# Rails select_tag value Does Not Save in Database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, activerecord

I have a form in rails using form_for where users are able to enter in information about an event. One of the options is a dropdown list for ages allowed. A

All of the other information on the form is being sent to the database however this value is never recorded.

The column datatype for :age is integer.

Here is how I'm currently implementing it.

```
<%= select_tag(:age, options_for_select([['All Ages', 1] , ['18+', 2] ,['21+', 3]])) %>
```

I can provide more information if needed.

Comment: u have used select_tag inside form_for..? check the name parameter of select tag..

Comment: add full form trace and your controller where u save it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your select tag seems to be disconnected from your model. Try [`select`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/select) instead:

```
<%= f.select :age, options_for_select([['All Ages', 1] , ['18+', 2] ,['21+', 3]]) %>
```

Comment: Great thanks @depa! Is it normally best to opt for select over select_tag?

Comment: If you want to be able to connect it to a form, then yes. Also take a look at `collection_select`: http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_select